# SQL to merge columns from 3 selects into one result, and consolidate rows with matching keys

Tags: sql

I have three select statements that each return a key and a column of data:

```
KEY     DATA_1
------- -------
A       123
B       456

KEY     DATA_2
------- -------
B       987
C       654
D       321

KEY     DATA_3
------- -------
D       234
E       567
```

How can I:

a) Merge the three data columns into one result set:

```
KEY     DATA_1   DATA_2  DATA_3
------- -------- ------- -------
A       123      NULL    NULL 
B       456      NULL    NULL
B       NULL     987     NULL
C       NULL     654     NULL
D       NULL     321     NULL
D       NULL     NULL    234
E       NULL     NULL    567
```

b) Consolidate the rows so that each key appears only once, with the appropriate data value in each column.

```
KEY     DATA_1   DATA_2  DATA_3
------- -------- ------- -------
A       123      NULL    NULL 
B       456      987     NULL
C       NULL     654     NULL
D       NULL     321     234
E       NULL     NULL    567
```

c) Replace the NULL values with a value of my choice, e.g. '000'

```
KEY     DATA_1   DATA_2  DATA_3
------- -------- ------- -------
A       123      000     000
B       456      987     000
C       000      654     000
D       000      321     234
E       000      000     567
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's answer this in order.

For 1:

```
select key, data_1, data_2, data_3
from ((select key, data_1, NULL as data_2, NULL as data_3
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select key, NULL, data_2, NULL
       from t2
      ) union all
      (select key, NULL, NULL, data_3
       from t3
      )
     ) t
```

For 2:

```
select key, max(data_1), max(data_2), max(data_3)
from ((select key, data_1, NULL as data_2, NULL as data_3
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select key, NULL, data_2, NULL
       from t2
      ) union all
      (select key, NULL, NULL, data_3
       from t3
      )
     ) t
group by key;
```

For 3:

```
select key, coalesce(max(data_1), '000'),
       coalesce(max(data_2), '000'), coalesce(max(data_3), '000')
from ((select key, data_1, NULL as data_2, NULL as data_3
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select key, NULL, data_2, NULL
       from t2
      ) union all
      (select key, NULL, NULL, data_3
       from t3
      )
     ) t
group by key;
```

The last example assumes that the data values are strings.  Otherwise, the `'000'` will be converted to a numeric 0.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.  The only modification I had to make was to remove the brackets around each individual select statement, but I think that is a Sybase thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 SELECT k.[key],
       Max(COALESCE(s1.data_1, '000')) data_1,
       Max(COALESCE(s2.data_2, '000')) data_2,
       Max(COALESCE(s3.data_3, '000')) data_3
FROM   (SELECT [key]
        FROM   select1
        UNION
        SELECT [key]
        FROM   select2
        UNION
        SELECT [key]
        FROM   select3) k
       LEFT JOIN select1 s1
              ON k.[key] = s1.[key]
       LEFT JOIN select2 s2
              ON k.[key] = s2.[key]
       LEFT JOIN select3 s3
              ON k.[key] = s3.[key]
GROUP  BY k.[key]
```

Some adjustments may be needed depending on `data_*` field type (numeric or varchar) and on the DB engine.

Beware : `key` is a SQL reserved keyword.